# How to create multiple variables with a value thats dynamic? for pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create aprox 20 graphs from 1989 to 2021, to filter them im using pandas

```
year1989 = ven_df['Year'] == '1989'
```

so with that variable i can use it as a 'mask' on

```
ven_df[year1989]
```

and output a dataframe with all the values only for 1989 on that

the problem is, they are so many years that i find very useless writing that same code 30 times or even more.

i want to use a loop or maybe a function that creates all the variables:
year1989 to year2021 with ven_df['Year'] == '1989' to ven_df['Year'] == '2021' as values.

is my approach correct? or is there a better way, im novice using pandas, thanks!

```
year1989 = ven_df['Year'] == '1989'
year1990 = ven_df['Year'] == '1990'
year1991 = ven_df['Year'] == '1991'
year1992 = ven_df['Year'] == '1992'
year1993 = ven_df['Year'] == '1993'
year1994 = ven_df['Year'] == '1994'
year1995 = ven_df['Year'] == '1995'
year1996 = ven_df['Year'] == '1996'
year1997 = ven_df['Year'] == '1997'
year1998 = ven_df['Year'] == '1998'
year1999 = ven_df['Year'] == '1999'
year2000 = ven_df['Year'] == '2000'
year2001 = ven_df['Year'] == '2001'
year2002 = ven_df['Year'] == '2002'
year2003 = ven_df['Year'] == '2003'
year2000 = ven_df['Year'] == '2004'
year2001 = ven_df['Year'] == '2005'
year2002 = ven_df['Year'] == '2006'
year2003 = ven_df['Year'] == '2007'
```

and soo on! im sure this is not the right way of doing things...

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. If your intent is to create many graphs, this can be easily done more simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
masks = {}
for year in range(1989, 2022):
    masks[str(year)] = ven_df['Year'] == str(year)
```

to access:

```
ven_df[masks['1995']]
```

Comment: you are a legend man, thanks, just what i needed and so simple.

Comment: Thank you! can you give an upvote and mark as a solution :)